# Trying to run a gulp task with VSCode which is not based in the root folder

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

This is my task.json

```
// A task runner configuration for gulp. Gulp provides a less task
// which compiles less to css. 
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "sfdcBuild",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always",
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
            "problemMatcher": "$lessCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately my gulp installation (the local one) is not under root but inside another folder:

```
root/js/
```

so how can I define that I would like to run this gulp command from inside the other folder?

PS: moving the task.json into the subfolder did nor work.

Comment: If have the same problem with a `make` command in linux, since the Makefile is stored in another location and `make -f DIR/Makefile` does not work for some other reasons. I tried to write a bash script to change to the directory and call the command from there, but in linux something strange happend when running a script from within VSCode.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using a different working directory is partly supported. It doesn't work for auto detection of gulp tasks but it should work for running gulp. You can add something like this to the tasks.json in the top level scope

```
"options": {
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/mySubDir"
},
```

However this still assumes that gulp and all node modules guld requires are accessible from that directory.

Comment: I made the mistake of originally using `${cwd}` instead of `${workspaceRoot}`. After hours of debugging why I kept getting "Maximum stack size exceeded" error, I realized it wasn't a gulp problem, but tasks.json issue. (since cwd was recursively being set)

Comment: Does anybody know how to make VS Code autodetect gulp tasks aren't in in the root?

Comment: I wish there was a way to give you beer through SO. I spent ages trying to solve this.

Comment: It also auto-detects now.

Comment: I have this same issue but this does not work, any idea why? (I already posted [the question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584507/how-to-run-cmake-in-visual-studio-code-using-tasks/49584630#49584630) )

Answer (score 1):

The [tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks) doesn't support at this time launching a task with a different `cwd`. One way to workaround it would be to create a `gulp.cmd` or `gulp.sh` file in your workspace's root folder that invokes the correct `gulp`. E.g. `gulp.cmd`:

```
@SETLOCAL
@SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
node  "%~dp0\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js" %*
```

To avoid committing this to your git repository, you could ignore it in `.git/info/exclude`

Answer (score 1):

you can pass path of your `gulpfile.js` to gulp in `args`

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [
    "--gulpfile",
    "./js/gulpfile.js"
]
```