# How to run Cmake in Visual Studio Code using tasks

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to run cmake with `ctrl+shift+B` like so:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "cmake",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
        },
        "command": "cmake ${workspaceRoot} -G \"MinGW Makefiles\"",
        (...)
    },
    {
        "label": "make",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mingw32-make.exe",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
        },
       (...),
        "dependsOn":["cmake"]
    },
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "dependsOn": ["make"]
    }
]
}
```

But no matter what I do It runs on ${workspaceRoot} instead of the ${workspaceRoot}/build one:

```
Executing task in folder cpppractice: cmake C:\workspace\cpp\cpppractice -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Is there anyhting wrong with this approach? As far as I understand the `cwd` variable in the `options` item should work.

Comment: why do this when the CMake Tools extension exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{
    "label": "cmake",
    "type": "shell",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
    },
    "command": "cmake \"MinGW Makefiles\"  ${workspaceFolder}",
},
```

This works, It seems that the "Executing task in folder cpppractice:" is not accurate and it is executing it in the correct place, as for why it did not work previously I think it's parsing the args incorrectly? I can't confirm, but here is the output:

```
Executing task in folder cpppractice: cmake "MinGW Makefiles"  
C:\workspace\cpp\cpppractice <

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/workspace/cpp/cpppractice/build
```

Where previously it was compalining about not being able Use the generator "MinGW" which means that it separating the argument "MinGW Makefiles".
After some tinkering I found out that this is also an answer:

```
{
        "label": "cmake",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
        },
        "command": "cmake",
        "args": [
            "-G",
            "'MinGW Makefiles'",
            "./.."
        ],
        ...
    },
```

I actually find the second approach a little bit cleaner but both work the same, So in order to pass an argument as a string you have to use single quotes like so:

```
...
"command":"echo",
"args": [
        "'Za Warudo!'",
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You pass arguments to `cmake` wrongly. The whole string `cmake ${workspaceRoot} -G "MinGW Makefiles"` is treated as a command name. Arguments must be listed in the `args` array.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmake",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
            },
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "-G",
                "\"MinGW Makefiles\""
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this, but the output is the same: `Executing task in folder cpppractice: cmake C:\workspace\cpp\cpppractice -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

Answer (score 1):

cmake now has a -B option that you can use to specify a build directory. No need to change directory before calling it. It will even create the build dir for you.