# Problem linking custom libraries with VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble linking my libraries to the main file in vscode. I've made a simple example:

main.cpp

```
#include "io.h"

int main()
{
    int x{read_number()};
    int y{read_number()};

    write_number(x + y);
    return 0;
}
```

io.h

```
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H

int read_number();
void write_number(int number);

#endif
```

io.cpp

```
#include "io.h"
#include <iostream>

int read_number()
{
    int x{};
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void write_number(int number)
{
    std::cout << "The answer is " << number << '\n';
}
```

Attempting to build this with g++ and these settings

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

results in

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2/main.cpp -I /home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2 -o /home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2/main <

/tmp/cca6uKjD.o: In function 'main':
/home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to 'read_number()'
/home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to 'read_number()'
/home/morten/learn_cpp/chp2/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to 'write_number(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I am used to using cmake instead so I am not quite sure how to do this with vscode. I have looked online and been recommended to pass the library path using the `-I` or `-L` flags to g++ but it doesn't seem to help anything.

Comment: I think you are not linking libraries. Your problem is here: `"${file}",` The documentation explains how to use more than 1 source file with Visual Studio Code here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: With that said if you wanted to build a library from `io.h` and `io.cpp` you probably want to use `CMake` with your `tasks.json`. Here is a question about that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584507/how-to-run-cmake-in-visual-studio-code-using-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584507/how-to-run-cmake-in-visual-studio-code-using-tasks)

Comment: If you're used to using cmake then use cmake and call that from the tasks. VS code's tasks really aren't suitable for compiling more than 1 cpp file

Comment: Install the extensions `ms-vscode.cmake-tools` and `twxs.cmake` and put a CMakeLists.txt in the root of your project. Now you can build, debug and run targets and tests from the bottom menu bar and you have syntax highlighting for CMake files.

Comment: Problem is I'm trying to use vscode to avoid having to write cmake config files, but maybe this isn't really an appropriate solution?

Comment: @drescherjm This works for lib files in the same directory, but I am getting "io.h not found" errors when using an `/inc` folder

Comment: ***but maybe this isn't really an appropriate solution?*** I would say it's more difficult and more work to do that instead of just using CMake.

Comment: ***but I am getting "io.h not found" errors when using an /inc*** Then you need to add `inc` to your Include path.