# vscode, mingw, g++, header files include fail from subdirectory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

Following the guideline on how to setup mingw g++ in vscode, I cannot seem to succeed in including headerfiles from a subdirectory. I have my working folder, in which my main.cpp lies. In that working folder, I have a subfolder called "inc" in which my header file add.h lies, and I have a subfolder "src" in which my add.cpp file lies. When I pass the argument to the compiler to include header files using the -I argument, it works fine. But this kind of contradicts the tutorial found on the vscode website that states that I should add include paths in the c_cpp_properties.json file:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

> You only need to add to the Include path array setting if your program includes header files that are not in your workspace or in the standard library path.

The build output message:

> C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\GitHub\CPP_Projects\00_helloworld_min*.cpp C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\GitHub\CPP_Projects\00_helloworld_min\src*.cpp -o C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\GitHub\CPP_Projects\00_helloworld_min\main.exe
> C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\GitHub\CPP_Projects\00_helloworld_min\main.cpp:2:17: fatal error: add.h: No such file or directory
> #include "add.h"

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

A simple minimalistic code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 15 and 5 is " << add(15, 5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A screenshot of my project to illustrate my inc and src folder:
[image: vscode]

My tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
                // "-I",
                // "${workspaceFolder}\\inc\\",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

My c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\**",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\inc\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: What happens when you uncomment the `-I` part of your tasks.json.

Comment: Did you try `"-I${workspaceFolder}\\inc\\",`

Comment: @drescherjm regarding your first question: then it works like a charm
regarding your second comment: Are we talking about the c_cpp_properties.json?

Comment: No `tasks.json` since that is used for building. `c_cpp_properties.json` is used for intellisense.

Comment: @drescherjm When I uncomment the -I argument in tasks.json, it works. But I am having difficulties to fully understand vscode and the C/C++ extension. How should I read the statement on the website then:
**If you want more control over the C/C++ extension, you can create a c_cpp_properties.json file, which will allow you to change settings such as the path to the compiler, include paths, C++ standard (default is C++17), and more.**

Comment: I do agree it is confusing that several of the settings are duplicated between `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`. You have to set the include path in both because they are separate. `tasks.json` args is basically the same command that executes to build your application if you built from the command line. I guess to make it less confusing they could have generated the `-I` for you from the setting in `c_cpp_properties.json` but then they would have to do this differently for different compilers. And `tasks.json` could do different things in the command than execute the compiler.

Comment: One example of not running the compiler directly is this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584507/how-to-run-cmake-in-visual-studio-code-using-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584507/how-to-run-cmake-in-visual-studio-code-using-tasks)

Comment: @drescherjm So c_cpp_properties.json does solely relate to the intellisense, and not to the compiler (arguments) / compilation of the program? If that is correct, then I understand that I need to manually put the -I argument in tasks.json if I want to include header files from a different subdirectory.

Comment: Yes c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense. I believe you could also use it to set environment variables that you make use of in your tasks.json